# Formalization of proof that there exists no bijective map from the integers to the naturals such that the ordering is preserved?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

My proof would go like: There exists a bijection from the naturals to the integers greater or equal than some number $N$ so that order is preserved(1 to N, 2 to N+1, 3 to N+2 etc.). $N$ must be finite because then the integers would have a minimum or maximum. But we need to make room for all the numbers less than $N$. We take a number $n$ less than $N$ and insert it in the function. We cannot insert it in the first place because then infinity would be the first place. But if we insert it in a place where it is not the first, then we would have the conclusion that $x<n<y$ where $x,y\geq N$, but $n<x\land n<y$, so we cannot insert it in a place where it is not the first place, meaning that we cannot insert anymore elements without disturbing the ordering.

The problem is that I don't know if this is correct or how to formalize it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $f: \Bbb{Z \to N}$ be the bijection.  If order is preserved, we must have $f(0) \lt f(1), f(-1) \lt f(0), f(-2) \lt f(-1) \ldots$ but this gives us an infinite descending chain of naturals, violating the well ordering principle.

Comment: Can it be generalized to say that there is no bijection from a set without minimum or maximum to a one with it s.t. ordering is preserved?

Comment: Yes.  Even simpler than the above, if you don't think $0 \in \Bbb N$, is to let $a=f^{-1}(1)$.  Then $f(a-1)$ must be less than $f(a)$ but there isn't one.  You can do the same trick with any predecessor of $a$